# python2: merge a list of csv elements

Tags: python

I have a dict like this:

```
{1: ['1,2,3', '4,5,6', '7,8']}
```

the dict can be variable in the number of list items but always 1 dict item. How do I merge it to

{1: ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8']}

?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need a list as the value? It will always contain only one element.

Comment: @MarkByers what options are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> d
{1: ['1,2,3', '4,5,6', '7,8'], 2: ['9,10', '11']}
>>> for k,v in d.iteritems():
...     d[k] = [",".join(v)]
...
>>> d
{1: ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'], 2: ['9,10,11']}
```

Comment: This works just as well with one dict item. The example merely showing that it can also handle multiple items if needed. BTW, wouldn't a simple variable suffice if you have only one item?

Answer (score 1):

in your case, you just need concat a string.

But if you want to merge the collection, try this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 5]
a.extend(b)
print a
```

> [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: Not what I was after as the number of collections can vary and your code expects a fixed number - however, I like the simplicity and will keep it for future code.